# subset and extract information from data frames in R

Tags: r, subset, lapply

I have a dataset naked named `data` in R with n variables, namely `X1,X2,...,Xn`. At some point of my code i find a subset named `subs` from another procedure, that gives the following output

```
        X1       X7       X8       X9      X11     
1    440.8065 466.9053 60.03588 374.8059 167.2424
```

Note that Xi values are not the same values from `data` and each `Xi` is the header, not a row in R.
For each of those `Xi` there are saved in the environment dataframes named `VarXi` (e.g. `VarX1, VarX2,..., VarXn`) of this form

```
      variable   coefficient
1  (Intercept) -2.111150e+03
2           X3  2.797371e-05
3           X5  5.653977e-01
4           X6  5.660470e+00
5           X7  1.003460e+01
6           X8  2.403519e+01
7          X10  3.931899e-01
8          X12  2.062661e+00
9          X13  5.430814e+00
10         X14  2.433546e-01
```

I want firstly to create a new dataset `newdata` that contains only the variables displayed in `subs`, and secondly (and most importantly) for only those `VarXi` displayed in `subs` to print only the the `abs(maximum coefficient)` and the corresponding variable of first column, eg.g based on above example

```
  variable   coefficient

1      X6    5.660470
```

How can i do those things in R?

Comment: *"there are saved in the environment dataframes named `sVarXi` (e.g. `sVarX1`, `sVarX2`,..., `sVarXn`) of this form"* This is pretty terrible. Your life will be easier if you use a list of data frames instead. [See my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17499013/how-do-i-make-a-list-of-data-frames/24376207#24376207) for details and examples.

Comment: thanks for your contribution, i had them in a list but in the end I wanted some of them separately from the others.

Comment: unlikely to be useful to anyone in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a reproducible example it's hard to tell, but this is my best guess for you:

```
# get a list of the "sVarXi" data frames:
svar_list = mget(ls(pattern = "svarX[0-9]+"))

# narrow down to just the ones in subs
svar_list_in_subs = svar_list[paste0("sVar", names(subs))]

# extract maximum row
max_coeffs = lapply(svar_list_in_subs, function(x) {
  x = x[x$variable != "(Intercept)", ]
  x[which.max(abs(x$coefficient)), ]
})
```

I'm saving `svar_list_in_subs` separately here just so the steps are clear - but it is duplicative and unnecessary. Once you have the `sVar` list, you could jump straight to:

```
max_coeffs_in_subs = lapply(svar_list[paste0("sVar", names(subs))], function(x) {
  x = x[x$variable != "(Intercept)", ]
  x[which.max(abs(x$coefficient)), ]
})
```

Comment: It displayed the following `Error in abs(x$coefficient) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function`

Comment: That could be for a few reasons - you would get that error if you tried to take the absolute value of a factor column or a non-existent column. Perhaps one of your `coefficient` columns isn't numeric? Or [perhaps the `mget` picked up a data frames that don't have the `coefficient` column? Or perhaps `names(subs)` includes the name of a data frame that doesn't exist or didn't make it into `svar_list`? Hmmm, maybe we need to paste "sVar" on to  the names of `subs`? I'll make that edit, but if you need more debugging help I can't do much without a reproducible example.

Comment: You should also be able to check the intermediate results and make sure they look right. Like, if `svar_list` has stuff, but `svar_list_in_subs` doesn't, then that's where the problem is.

Comment: I think i locate what the problem might be, in all cases `max_coeffs` return the `(Intercept)` as the result, how can i make it ignore it in the calculations?

Comment: Sorry, can not run it because of too much syntax error

Comment: Sorry, can not debug because no reproducible example to test on.

Comment: Okay, I found  missing `]` and put it in, but seriously it's hard to debug code that I can't run because there is no input. If you need more help, share a reproducible example.

Comment: We might getting closer to the solution. When i ran `svar_list`, everything is good. When i  run the `svar_list_in_subs` i nstead of having a list of 6 `svarX`, i have six empty lists. Is there any other command instead of paste0 to make it display lists for only `subs` displayed variables?

Comment: What is `names(subs)` and what is `names(svar_list)`? Adding `dput(subs)` to your question would help a lot.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222735/discussion-between-nickolakis-and-gregor-thomas).

Comment: So, the problem is that `ssVarX` doesn't have names. If you created it with `mget` like I showed, it should have the names of the objects that went into it, and that we can build out of the column names of `subs`. But it doesn't have any names. If you created it manually as `ssVarX = list(ssVarX1, ssVarX2, ...)` then go back and give it names, `ssVarX = list(ssVarX1 = ssVarX1, ssVarX2 = ssVarX2, ...)`, or use `mget` or some other method so that it has names. As long as you can build the names of `ssVarX` out of the column names of `subs`, the rest should work.

Comment: I created it with the one you showed first but it didn't include all variables, so i tried to use the `ssVarX` list that already existed in my code

Comment: You can play around with the `ls(pattern = "svarX[0-9]+")` to get the list of objects to work. Maybe you need the capital V `pattern = "sVarX[0-9]+"`. Or maybe you need "ss" instead of "s"...

Comment: i manage to make it work before writing like that `svar_list = mget(ls(pattern = "ssVarX[0-9]+"))``, having the  wanted results but `svar_list_in_subs` was giving me empty  `list of 6'. Maybe subs have not names too? can that be the problem?

Comment: I made it work, thanks for all your help, it was a syntax error made by me.